# Wpf DataGrid SelectedItem loses binding after cell edit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a collection of items (Rules). If I edit one of these items manually in the DataGrid, it seems like the `SelectedItem` binding on the grid stops working (`RuleListViewModelPropertyChanged` in the controller is never called again). But only if I actually change the value of the item in the cell, otherwise `SelectedItem` keeps working like it should.

I have stripped the code of some irrelevant things, so this is basically what I have. First, I have the following `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RuleTable" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRule, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               BorderThickness="0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                  ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                Header="{x:Static p:Resources.TargetValue}" Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellElementStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellEditingStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

With a `ViewModel` that looks like this:

```
public class RuleListViewModel : ViewModel<IRuleListView>
{
    private IEnumerable<Rule> rules;
    private Rule selectedRule;

    public RuleListViewModel(IRuleListView view)
        : base(view)
    {
    }

    public RuleListViewModel() : base(null) {}

    public IEnumerable<Rule> Rules
    {
        get
        {
            return rules;
        }
        set
        {
            if (rules != value)
            {
                rules = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Rules");
            }
        }
    }

    public Rule SelectedRule
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedRule;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedRule != value)
            {
                selectedRule = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRule");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally a `Controller` that looks like this:

```
public class RuleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IShellService shellService;
    private readonly RuleListViewModel ruleListViewModel;

    private readonly DelegateCommand addRuleCommand;
    private readonly DelegateCommand deleteRuleCommand;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public RuleController(IShellService shellService, IEntityService entityService, RuleListViewModel ruleListViewModel)
    {
        this.shellService = shellService;
        this.ruleListViewModel = ruleListViewModel;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        AddWeakEventListener(ruleListViewModel, RuleListViewModelPropertyChanged);
        shellService.RuleListView = ruleListViewModel.View;

        List<Rule> rules = GetRules();
        ruleListViewModel.Rules = new ObservableCollection<Rule>(rules);
    }

    private void RuleListViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedRule")
        {
            // This never gets called after edit
        }
    }
}
```

I have really no idea what the problem is, but since I actually have to change the value to experience this behavior (only clicking in the cell and not editing anything works fine) I'm guessing it has something to do with the `SelectedItem` binding breaking when I change the value of the item bound to it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it was because I forgot to let my data model inherit from `System.Waf.Applications.DataModel` (Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm using WPF Application Framework).

I guess it had to do with `PropertyChanged` events not being handled.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who comes across this thread and you are using ObservableCollection - check to see if you override GetHashCode() (I was doing equality testing via IEquatable). The bindings to SelectedItem and SelectedIndex break as soon as you make a change to a cell.

From MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code."

And of course I was getting a hash on the editable (i.e. mutable) field...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because datagrid uses Bindingroups, So when you entered in a cell every UI event is by-passed until you validate and leave the row.

read this post it might helps :[WPF DataGrid source updating on cell changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028556/wpf-datagrid-source-updating-on-cell-changed)

Comment: Thank you for your input, but that wasn't the case. It was because my `DataModel` didn't inherit from `System.Waf.Applications.DataModel` (Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm using WPF Application Framework)