# WPF DataGrid SelectedItem binding stops working after item change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My problem/situation is very similar to [Wpf DataGrid SelectedItem loses binding after cell edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260943/wpf-datagrid-selecteditem-loses-binding-after-cell-edit) but I'm not using any "custom" WPF framework. I have a model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IEditableObject`, and a grid bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. The grid's `SelectedItem` property is bound to a property on the VM.

With a break point, I can see my `ViewModel.SelectedItem` property change as I select different rows in the grid. The moment I change a value on a row, however, the `ViewModel.SelectedItem` property is no longer set as I change focus on the rows. The solution identified in the above link does not work since I'm not using a custom WPF framework, just naked WPF.

Any ideas?

```
// View model area
public IPurchaseorderItem SelectedItem
{
    get 
    { 
        return _selectedItem;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem != value)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            SelectItemCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
            RemoveItemCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}

// XAML SelectedItem binding
<views:NoBindingGroupDataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  

// Special Grid to clear binding groups (read on a similarly themed SO question/answer)
internal sealed class NoBindingGroupDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    private bool _editing = false;

    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        var desiredSize = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
        ClearBindingGroup();
        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellEditEnding(e);

        if (!_editing)
        {
            _editing = true;

            CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);

            _editing = false;
        }
    }

    private void ClearBindingGroup()
    {
        ItemBindingGroup = null;

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var row = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;

            if (row != null)
            {
                row.BindingGroup = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your selecteditem property you should just call onpropertychanged for selecteditem and not the command stuff. why cant you use the normal datagrid?

Comment: Why do you do this:row.BindingGroup = null?maybe you remove the binding yourself.And would you add    `SelectItemCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
RemoveItemCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();` implementations?Because as `blindmeis` said you can just call `onpropertychanged` for selecteditem.

Comment: @blindmeis : Your comment is unrelated to the question being asked. To answer your question, though: The VM does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged directly (it is applied via aspects.) Although it used to, WPF no longer "polls" ICommand.CanExecute() therefore I have to notify the Command instance when a change it cares about may have occurred.

Comment: @raha: See my last comment for blindmeis regarding NotifyCanExecuteChanged(). To answer your other concern, however: Setting BindingGroup to null was another (potential) solution I found online for the issue I'm having, but it does not work. The problem persist either way, so I didn't think there would be any harm in including it here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the SelectedItem dependency property on DataGrid is broken and not being used correctly. After some debugging using OnPropertyChanged, I found that the grid is actually setting a "CurrentItem" property reliably. I changed to use CurrentItem instead and everything appears to work correctly... the user's "selected row" is being sent to the VM without incident.

Comment: I need to get the row count. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Killercam Row count or selected index? Row count is ideally the Length/Count of the array to which the view is bound (on your vm.) meaning you already have access to this information.

Comment: CurrentItem does seem to work better. It doesn't seem to support null, though. I need to start with nothing selected.