# WPF - Bind an enum to DatagridComboBoxColumn with TwoWay mode

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, datagridcomboboxcolumn, two-way-binding

I am trying to create a `DataGrid` table with the `DatagridComboBoxColumn` column having available selections from an enum. The current code below can only binds the enum value `OneWay` from the binding `PaletteColors`. I want the enum value in `PaletteColors[x].Type` to be updated when the user selects an enum value from the drop-down list. How do we update the xaml to do that?

**Table.xaml**

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- 
        Resource for displaying enum values
        -->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PaletteColorInterfaceTypes"
                            MethodName="GetValues" 
                            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="enums:PaletteColorInterfaceType" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid
              IsReadOnly="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PaletteColors}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Location" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PaletteColorInterfaceTypes}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Type}" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ColorSelectedCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding CellEditedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Enum**

```
public enum PaletteColorInterfaceType
{
    Invalid = 0,
    A,
    B,
}
```

**PaletteColor.cs**

```
public class PaletteColor : IEquatable<PaletteColor>
{
    public PaletteColor(
        string name,
        PaletteColorInterfaceType type)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PaletteColorInterfaceType Type { get; set; }
}
```

**TableViewModel.cs**

```
public SortableObservableCollection<PaletteColor> PaletteColors { get; }

public PaletteColor SelectedColor { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried this code now and seems to work fine?

Comment: Yeah, it would work if it loads the types from the list `PaletteColors` and displays the values in the cells. However, if I want to select a different value from the cell, the new selected value of the cell is not reflected in the list `PaletteColors`. Basically it works as a OneWay mode only.

Comment: Sorry, I've read what you've written just now about 10 times and I still can't quite figure out what it is you're trying to do (I'm guessing that's why nobody else has responded to this either). Your DataGrid currently reflects the list of PaletteColors, with the currently selected one bound to SelectedColor. Each cell in the DataGridComboBoxColumn shows the full list of possible PaletteColorInterfaceType values, and selecting them updates Type in the curent SelectedColor. This is normal usage, and also how your code currently behaves, what other behaviour exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Oh my apology for the confusion. You pointed out the `SelectedColor`, which I was not thinking of using it to check the updated value when a cell is updated to the new enum value. I was thinking of looking at the values in `PaletteColors` instead. As I started looking into the `SelectedColor`, I find that the selected item is not bound correctly. I don't see `SelectedColor` has the value of the row being selected. Do you see a problem with it?

Comment: Seemed to work fine for me, I put a breakpoint on the SelectedColor setter and it was definitely getting hit when the selection changed. and with value set to the correct element. Only thing I changed in your code was making PaletteColors of type ObservableCollection<PaletteColor>, as I don't have the source code for SortableObservableCollection you're using.

Comment: Oh ok. My setter is not called when a row is selected. How do you create the event triggers? I updated the xaml above to have the event triggers.

Comment: No no, you're already binding SelectedItem to the SelectedColor property, so you don't need event triggers. Like I said, when I pasted your code into a test app it worked fine for me, there must be something else in your code interfering that you haven't posted here.

Comment: Actually, the binding lost after a cell's value is edited. The issue is that the `GetHashCode()` in the `PaletteColor` class was overridden, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309915/wpf-datagrid-selecteditem-binding-stops-working-after-item-change.
Thank you so much Mark for your help and suggestion.