# WPF DataGrid: Need Binding to Occur ASAP

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I was having the delayed-binding problem mentioned here:

[WPF DataGrid source updating on cell changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028556/wpf-datagrid-source-updating-on-cell-changed)

My source properties were being updated when the user pressed **Enter** but not when s/he pressed **Tab**.

I found an excellent advice in the post above: `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` (that is the answer with most upclicks, BTW) and now the updates are done as desired, when the user leaves the cell horizontally or vertically. One problem remains, however: pressing **Enter** while in the bottom row.

The relevant columns are defined as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Isn't there something like: `UpdateSourceTrigger=EditEnded`  ??

Posterior addition:

The `Explicit` option seems quite promising:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

My event handler would only care about events triggered by the last row and call the `UpdateSource` method. If that is the solution, I only need to know what to place to the left of `.UpdateSource()`.??

Comment: The `Explicit` option requires you to manually inform a change. Did you tried the `PropertyChanged`option? It's the default option, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` is not the default option for text controls, such as DataGrid cells. The notification would not be a problem since I already have a trigger on `DataGrid_CellEditEnding` (currently for debugging). All I need is to repurpose it, adding an `UpdateSource` but don't know what to prepend to it.

Comment: My `Binding` experience was with MVVM. I set the ViewModel as the `DataContext` and let the 'magic' of the `OnPropertyChanged` do it's work. Are you using MVVM?

Comment: I am using the `ProperyChanged` magic with a couple columns that contain ComboBoxes and are defined in a very fancy fashion. Those work perfectlty. I have read about MVVM but seems to be an overkill for my simple DataGrid.

Comment: In fact, my next attempt was to define my plain text (non-ComboBox) columns (the ones giving me trouble) in a more complex way, but don't know where to start.

Comment: Yes, that's the general consensus, but you use it in your whole project, not in just one Control. But it does have it's payoffs.

Comment: Have you tried the `CurrentCellChanged` Event?

Comment: I thought MVVM was a methodology, a way of organizing folders in MSVS. I don't have any kind of hierarchy in my apps: all they do is read a set of XML files and place some of the fields in the DataGrid, one row for every XML file. At the end, an Excel spreadsheet is generated.

Comment: Yes, I have tried `CurrentCellChanged`. Decided that `CellEditEnding` fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: @TravisBanger MVVM is about separating UI from business logic, and nothing else. has nothing to do with folders or else

Comment: MVVM is more of an architecture. Separation of responsibilities and much more. If you're into WPF you should definitely check it out.

Comment: "MVVM is about separating UI from business logic" In this tiny rectangle, I feel forced to simplify and abbreviate. I am reading the 3 recommended articles about MVVM.

Comment: @TravisBanger it's really simple, no need to overcomplicate. It all boils down to **1** - "Do not Manipulate UI Elements in procedural code in WPF, that's what XAML is for" and **2** - "Never ever ever put any business logic in Code Behind".

Comment: @HighCore: I have 2 columns with ComboBoxes. The left column values must always be larger or equal to the right column. I was given that constraint by the head of engineering, so it qualifies as business logic, and I placed it in Code Behind (you solved that problem for me, when I had to create a web page just to ask/explain the question). Have no idea how to place it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this:

```
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" 
                       Width="Auto" 
                       Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   </DataGridTextColumn>
```

And it works fine. The binding is updated on every key press, rather than when changing the row or else.

Comment: I saw that in the Microsoft link. I shudder to think of the waste of perfectly good CPU cycles. :-)

Comment: Okay, let me try `PropertyChanged` again. I think it didn't work for me for some reason...